# Incorrect selenium timeouts

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have a code snippet as the following below.  Before I list it I want to let you know that

waitForXPathVisibility (error, seconds, sleep, unit, xpath);

does basically the same as a

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, seconds * 1000, sleep * 1000);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xpath)));
```

"error" is the error message to print upon timeout.  So I have code

```
    try {
        waitForXPathVisibility("applicationStatusTab", seconds, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS, APP_STATUS_TAB_SELECTED_X);
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        // There seems to be some sort of problem with it not waiting the full amount
        // or throwin an error when there is not, so check for that.
        System.out.println("Timout After: " + new Date() + " ... This may NOT be an actual error:");
        if (!isXPathDisplayed(APP_STATUS_TAB_SELECTED_X)) {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

We tell it what time unit to use.  I have specified seconds.

Now the page takes a long time to load.  Without the try, the page would wait maybe 90 seconds or so, and throw a timeout error.  I added the catch and now it catches it and does not give an error, because the xpath is there even though it times out and sait it wasn't:

```
WARNING: WebDriverException thrown by findElement(By.xpath: 
//div[@id='pt1:r1']//a[contains(@id,'disAcr') and 
contains(text(),'Application Status')  and contains(@class,'Selected') ])
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: timeout
```

However, the isXPathDisplayed() succeeds. (This method basically takes the xpath, does a findElementsBy() and verifies the size is at least one.

What I am wondering is, since the page takes so long to display, somehow when the find operates, it finds the element before the page is displayed in Chrome.  (I have seen that before that the page code is available and ready but sometimes it takes Chrome a while to update the display).

So perhaps the find in the wait() finds the element and exits but since the page is not displayed on the terminal yet, something else may think the element is not there and throw the error.

Does this make sense?  Is there some sort of wait you can issue that will wait until the Chrome display matches the code that Selenium is looking at?  Or am I barking up the wrong tree?

As an aside, even though I catch the error the stack backtrace is still shown, though the catch is successful and the program continues.

Oh, and this is Java with Eclipse and Selenium and Chrome.

Comment: Even waiting for a stale element from the page I am moving FROM times out after a minute or so even though I tell it to wait 10 minutes max.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of factors which you need to consider as follows :

- First of all the function **`waitForXPathVisibility (error, seconds, sleep, unit, xpath);`** looks as a overhead to me. There is basically no need to write a seperate wrapper function on top of **`WebDriverWait`**.
- As you mentioned the function **`waitForXPathVisibility (error, seconds, sleep, unit, xpath);`** in your code is same as **`WebDriverWait`**. Let us have a look at **`WebDriverWait`**.

### **`WebDriverWait`**

As per the current implementation of **`WebDriverWait`** in **`Selenium v3.8.1`** the **Constructors** are as follows :

- **`WebDriverWait(WebDriver driver, Clock clock, Sleeper sleeper, long timeOutInSeconds, long sleepTimeOut)`**
- **`WebDriverWait(WebDriver driver, long timeOutInSeconds)`**

  WebDriverWait will ignore instances of `NotFoundExceptio`n that are encountered by default in the `until` condition.
- **`WebDriverWait(WebDriver driver, long timeOutInSeconds, long sleepInMillis)`**

  WebDriverWait will ignore instances of `NotFoundException` that are encountered by default in the `until` condition.

---

### About this Question

As per your question, it is pretty much unclear why you needed a function like `waitForXPathVisibility (error, seconds, sleep, unit, xpath);` as :

- **`error`** - The `until` condition will always ignore the `NotFoundException` (error)
- **`seconds`** - The `long timeOutInSeconds` itself is available.
- **`sleep`** - The `long sleepInMillis` is available.
- **`xpath`** - Which can be passed to `ExpectedConditions`.

As you mentioned `page takes a long time to load` and `wait maybe 90 seconds`, `WebDriverWait` if configured in such a way wouldn't complain either.

Now, without looking at the code or the relevant `HTML` it would be tough to analyze further. But a few points :

- The `xpath` you have constructed as below is logically correct but would be low on performance. We can always construct a better `xpath`
  **`org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: timeout`** exception can stem out any of the following `ExpectedConditions` :

  ```
  elementToBeClickable(By locator)
  elementToBeSelected(By locator) 
  elementSelectionStateToBe(By locator, boolean selected)
  ```
- Even after throwing **`org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: timeout`** the element can be **visible**. Hence **`isXPathDisplayed()` succeeds**

---

### Solution

Without any visibility to your next action post **`WebDriverWait`** a simple solution would be to :

- Set `wait time` to **120 seconds**.
- Set `Polling` at **1000 milli seconds**
- Set `ExpectedConditions` to **elementToBeClickable(By locator)**

Comment: Hey to answer one of your questions, the upper-level muckety mucks wrote the waitForXpathVisibility() and would like us to use it.  I did try a regular WebDriverWait also and had the same issue.  I read through your comments and I will read through again because there is a lot there for which I thank you very much (though I guess we are not supposed to thank people?)

Comment: OK.  I hesitate to show code because people have been reprimanded by their companies for publishing confidential code.  I did try your solution but it gave the same error. .  "WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, seconds, 1000);" ... "wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(APP_STATUS_TAB_SELECTED_X)));"

Comment: Go ahead, let me know if any counter questions !!! What does the error says? Can you update the original question with the last updated code and the complete Error Stack Trace?

Comment: OK but I better get permission first?